# C# Bind value of datagridview column to DataTable

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have a DataTable as a data source of a GridView.  I'm adding a combo box the the GridView .

I'd like to be able to add a column to the DataTable that would automatically update with the value the user selects in the GridView.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

and the answer is...

```
DataTable myTable = getYourDataByMagic();

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn box = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.add("choice one");
bs.add("choice two");

box.HeaderText = "My Choice";
box.Name = "select";
box.DataSource = bs;
box.DataPropertyName = "select";

myTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("select"));
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(box);
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = myTable;
```

now, your "myTable" will update with the values selected in the combobox

Answer (score 0):

I'd put two grids side by side one containing all info and one that just had the blank column. I would update the datatable with the grid that contained the one column.  This would  be update based on selected index of the previous grid.  First thing to come to mind.